# How to apply .timestamp attribute to a column?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, attributes

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(data=[[pd.Timestamp.now()],[pd.Timestamp.now()],[pd.Timestamp.now()],[pd.Timestamp.now()]],columns=['Date'])
    
df
                        Date
0 2022-01-19 12:15:40.801133
1 2022-01-19 12:15:40.801192
2 2022-01-19 12:15:40.801202
3 2022-01-19 12:15:40.801210

df.Date[0]
Timestamp('2022-01-19 12:15:40.801133')

df.Date[0].timestamp()
1642594540.801133
```

How can apply the .timestamp attribute to the entire column of the dataframe ?
Thank you.

Comment: Use `print (pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).astype(np.int64) / 10**9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply()`:

```
df["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.timestamp())
```

**Output:**

```
0    1.642594e+09
1    1.642594e+09
2    1.642594e+09
3    1.642594e+09
Name: Date, dtype: float64
```

---

Or if you want to change the existing column:

```
df["Date"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.timestamp())

df

    Date
0   1.642594e+09
1   1.642594e+09
2   1.642594e+09
3   1.642594e+09
```